# unsubscribe selected subscribers from node in xmpp

Tags: xmpp, publish-subscribe, openfire

in  [xmpp publish subscribe protocol](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0060.html) there is a provision to subscribe and unsubscribe to a node. but what if a publisher itself want to temporarily unsubscribe some of the subscribers and keep on publishing to selected subscribers only.

for example 
A , B and C has subscribed to node `PIZZA` now if after somepoint if `PIZZA` node wants to publish only to A and C but not B.

i read the protocol but i didn't find anything like this , so is there anyone has any idea how to do it ?

i am using `openfire` as server and `asmack libs` as client

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about xmpp, maybe this is standard practice there, but normally the publisher doesn't know anything about the receivers so shouldn't control who is subscribed. Why does the publisher know better than the receiver whether the receiver should receive?

I would try a different approach, such as adding data in the message so the receiver can decide whether they should ignore the message.

Sending a blank message would not likely work: then all receivers that handle message only if not blank will skip it. So it will only work if B does not filter on blank messages. Instead, if the message has "filter=...", then receivers can decide to process based on the value of filter. Like, perhaps receivers A and C are a Type "X" of receiver, and receivers B and D are a type "Y" of receiver. Then if filter = "X", then receivers B and D know to ignore it. If filter is "Y", A and C know to ignore it. If filter is empty, they all process it.

Comment: okay , so better i  try sending blank messages to receiver rather then unsubscribing them , wht say